# how to add beginning of file to another file using loop

Tags: bash, grep

I have files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and 1-bis.txt, 2-bis.txt, 3-bis.txt

```
cat 1.txt
#ok
#5 
6 
5

cat 2.txt
#not ok
#56
13
56

cat 3.txt
#nothing
#

cat 1-bis.txt
5
4

cat 2-bis.txt
32
24

cat 3-bis.txt
```

I would like to add lines starting with # (from non bis files) at the beginning of files "bis" in order to get:

```
cat 1-bis.txt
#ok
#5
5
4

cat 2-bis.txt
#not ok
#56
32
24

cat 3-bis.txt
#nothing
#
```

I was thinking to use `grep -P "#"` to select lines with # (or maybe `sed -n`) but I don't know how to loop files to solve this problem

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```sh
for f in *-bis.txt; do
  { grep '^#' "${f//-bis}"; cat "$f"; } > "$f.tmp" && mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
done
```

---

If you only want `#` lines at the beginning of the files only then use:

Change

```
grep '^#' "${f//-bis}"
```

with:

```
awk '!/^#/{exit}1' "${f//-bis}"
```

Comment: This will add all lines starting with `#`, even if they are not in the preamble of the `N.txt` file. If this is not what the OP want, instead of `grep '^#'`, we could use `awk '!/^#/{exit}1'` that will select only the first lines of `N.txt` starting with `#`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: May be I misunderstood but OP wrote this: `I would like to add lines starting with # (from non bis files) at the beginning of files "bis"` which is what I did in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava Absolutely, you perfectly answered the OP (reason why I upvoted). But as all given examples have the `#` lines at the beginning of the files it could be that this extra feature is also required and the OP forgot to mention it. This is why I commented, just in case.

Comment: Yeah thanks @RenaudPacalet I have added nice `awk` based solution in my answer as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `?.txt` files and use parameter expansion to derive the corresponding bis- filename:

```sh
for file in ?.txt ; do
    bis=${file%.txt}-bis.txt
    grep '^#' "$file" > tmp
    cat "$bis" >> tmp
    mv tmp "$bis"
done
```

You don't need `grep -P`, simple grep is enough. Just add `^` to only match the octothorpes at the beginning of a line.